# Part of html not executed

Tags: php, html

This is the code I wrote:

```
<a class="message" id="newMessage">New Message</a>
<a class="message" id="inbox">Inbox <?php if($messageNumber1 > 0): ?>(<?php echo $messageNumber1; ?>)<?php endif;?></a>
<a class="message" id="outbox">Outbox</a>
<a href="logout.php" id="logout">Logout</a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this part of site is not loaded into browser. When I check HTML with Firebug or Chrome developer tools I can't find these lines of code and I don't see anything wrong with this. Please help

Comment: Could you add the whole file? If this is not appearing, then it's probably something on the preceding lines that's breaking.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mnaWrQc5 this is full code

Comment: And what is the last part that's executed? Have you checked your website's error logs? Checked that all your queries are succeeding?

Comment: @Malcolm - that's the alternative syntax for `if` statements. It's valid: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @andrewsi everything is executed until 190-th line of code

Comment: @andrewsi you are correct I never knew that :/ so removed my comment

Comment: @Malcolm - PHP's great for having things like alternate syntax like that. And by great, I mean incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @Alen I don't know where the problem could be. All I can think of are the `( )` in `(<?php echo $messageNumber1; ?>)` which could be the culprits.

Comment: The code looks all right, do you have error_reporting turned on?

Comment: @Alen Is `session_start();` inside ALL files, including your included files?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it is, that's not problem. Everything else works, my only problem is those 'button' on the end of file. This worked 2 days ago and I don't know what changed

Comment: @Alen Then it must be in your DB then. If there are messages piling up and the query is not matching, then that would explain it, or could explain it. Very hard, if not impossible to test your code.

Comment: It's not DB problem, if I delete php commands from html I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="message" id="inbox">Inbox <?php if($messageNumber1 > 0): ?>(<?php echo $messageNumber1; ?>)<?php endif;?></a>
```

change this line to

```
<a class="message" id="inbox">Inbox <?php if($messageNumber1 > 0){ ?>(<?php echo $messageNumber1; ?>)<?php } ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simplified version of your line

```
<a class="message" id="inbox">Inbox <?php if($messageNumber1 > 0) { echo '('.$messageNumber1.')';  } ?></a>
```

Comment: You should check this: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/03/10/php-if-else-endif-statements/

Answer (score 0):

Try it simply

```
<a class="message" id="inbox">
  Inbox <?php if($messageNumber1 > 0) { echo '('.$messageNumber1.')';  } ?>
</a>
```